# Resize Image to Fit to Canvas using drawImage, Max Width

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working with some large images (Wide but not high) and resizing them to fit to a canvas using the the drawImage Function.

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,IW,IH,0,0,CW,CH);
```

I noticed some images do not load correctly. After some investigation it appears to be only on images where IW > 16384.

If there is no resizing, the canvas is the correct size for the image, then it works.

Does anyone know the limits of these parameters?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by some rudimentary tiling

```
if (IW > 16000) {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, IW/2, IH, 0, 0, CW/2, CH);
   ctx.drawImage(img, IW/2, 0, IW/2, IH, CW/2, 0, CW/2, CH);
} else {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, IW, IH, 0, 0, CW, CH);
}
```

Though I'm still unware of the fundamental restriction on drawImage size